# Service Message broker services in Starting - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, windows-server-2012-r2, workflow2013

One of our SharePoint 2013 Production server is updated & its Framework updated to 4.6.1

Now Service Message Broker service status is starting which not allows us to start, stop &  Restart, cause SharePoint 2013 workflows not working on Prod server.
[image]
﻿

*As per research I found that windows is updated we need to update Service bus 1.0 to 1.1 as well. I download update of Service bus from [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36794) link. When I run the setup it gives me error: **An unexpected internal error has occurred***

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue before when trying **[installing SharePoint 2013 prerequisites on a server that has .Net framework 4.6.1 installed](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/this-product-requires-microsoft-net-framework-4-5-sharepoint-2013-setup-failed/).**

But in your case, Framework 4.6.1 has been installed on a server that has already SharePoint installed. Therefore, maybe the **[Service Bus Ports are blocked](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-port-is-blocked/)**

**So in this case, try to do the following :**

- **[Force Stopping Service Bus Message Broker.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/service-bus-message-broker-stuck-on-starting/#Force-Stopping-Service-Bus-Message-Broker)**
- Ensure you have rebooted since the installation of .NET 4.6.1 so that further management can occur.
- Make sure all **[other workflow manager services are up and running](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-health-checklist-in-sharepoint/)**.
- Follow the instructions mentioned at **[Service Bus Message Broker Stuck on Starting](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/service-bus-message-broker-stuck-on-starting)**
- In the end, Try to uninstall.Netframework 4.6.1 as mentioned [here](http://majorbacon.blogspot.com/2016/05/uninstall-net-framework-461-if-you-are.html)

> **Note:** you get the Internal error when you tried to install Cumulative Update for Service Bus 1.0 (KB2799752), this usually occurs if the service bus 1.0 may be not installed.

- You may need to run the SharePoint configuration wizard on all SharePoint servers within the farm.

> For more details, check, **[Service Bus Message Broker Stuck on Starting](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/service-bus-message-broker-stuck-on-starting)**

Answer (score 1):

Can you go to services.msc and check if the Windows Fabric host service is up and running ?

If it is not running, you might need to restart this service and then try to stop and restart your service message broker service.