# updating SharePoint workflow manager CU5 errored

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow-manager, update

After trying to install the update, my windows service "Service Bus message broker struck in starting state. From the logs, i found the error.

> Complete-WFHostUpgrade : The remote server returned an error: (404)
>   Not Found.  The incoming request is not recoginzed as a namespace
>   policy put request:  Unrecognized policy type:
>   SubscriptionDescription, http://schemas.microsoft.com
>   /netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect.TrackingId:47baa270-c316-4c71-a7ad-e75d
>   0a577d22_Gshrd-rlg-spap3s,TimeStamp:12/10/2018 9:12:13 PM At
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\E-Business Servers 
>   Updates\Updates\Uninstall4055730\UnifiedWFHotfixUpgrade.PS1:643 char:5
>   +           Complete-WFHostUpgrade -TargetWFVersion $TargetWFVersion
>   +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Complete-WFHostUpgrade], Messag     ingEntityNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WFServiceUpgradeFailed,Microsoft.Workflow.Deploy
>   ment.Commands.CompleteWFHostUpgrade

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?
I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like permission issue, Please make sure Service accounts (Running the services) has right permission on the Workflow & Service Bus databases.

also try to stop the SB host and then start it. using Stop-SBHost & Start-SBHost.

Comment: it is running with an installation account which has admin permissions. "Stop-SBHost" didnt finish execution, probably because service  "Service Bus message broker" was stuck in starting state.

Comment: few blogs showed installing "Workflow manager 1.0 refresh (CU2)" from web platform fixes the issue, but i am already on Workflow manager Cumulative Update 5, installed successfully.

Comment: try to restart the server

Comment: Did couple of times, but still the service is stuck in starting State

Comment: Do u have azure service bus 1.1 update installed

Comment: Ours is on Prem 2013 SharePoint, is it required?

Comment: Yes that required

Comment: Ok, is there any specific process to install or I can proceed with my current cu5 update?

Comment: Starting "Service Buses" from services.msc helped

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the Windows Fabric Host Service is running.

If the Windows Fabric Host Service is not running, please start it, then try to start the Service Bus Message Broker again.

If you cannot stop the broker service while starting, got to task manager and kill Microsoft.ServiceBus Message Broker process.

References:

https://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2012/09/18/servicebus-message-broker-service-is-starting-and-starting.aspx

[Service Message broker services in Starting - SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200507/service-message-broker-services-in-starting-sharepoint-2013)